How to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\log (x)} \, dx$
I have tried different substitutions and transformations, but am not getting a lead. Any suggestion would be helpful.
The numerical value of the integral is around $-3.2192$.
Interestingly these two seem to diverge:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (3 x)}{\log (x)} \, dx$$
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (4 x)}{\log (x)} \, dx$$

That the convergence of $I(t):=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(tx)}{\log(x)}dx$ happens only for special values of $t$ is not surprising, as the integrand $\frac{\sin(tx)}{\log(x)}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $x=1$ when $t$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$. Therefore, $I(t)$ can only converge when $t\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$.

It is not even obvious that the given integral converges. You should work this out. The numerical value is no proof because numerical values sometimes fail to detect divergency or at least can give very bad approximations.

See $\tt WolframAlpha$ result

what about feynman's trick or a double integral?
$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t\sin(\pi x)}{\log x}dx$$

Partial answer: I can solve the integral from $x=0$ to $x=1$, and give convincing evidence in favour of convergence from $x=1$ to $x=\infty$.
For the first part, note that $\log(x)<0$ and thus $\frac{1}{-\log(x)} = \int_0^\infty x^y\,\text{d}y$.
Inserting this into the integral gives
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\log(x)}\,\text{d}x &= -\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 x^y \sin(\pi x)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\\
&= -\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 x^{y+2n+1}\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\\
&= -\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \int_{2n+2}^\infty \frac{1}{y}\,\text{d}y\\
&= -\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \left[ \log(L) - \log(2n+2) \right]\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \log(n+1) - \sin(\pi) \lim_{L\rightarrow\infty} \log(L/2)\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \log(n+1) = -1.4912348567...,
\end{align}
which matches numerical integration (although admittedly the interchanging of limits here is justified by nothing other than the numerical agreement).
Similarly, for $x=1$ to $x=\infty$ we can rewrite the integral as
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\log(x)}\,\text{d}x &= \int_0^\infty \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^y} \,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y = \int_0^\infty f(y)\,\text{d}y,
\end{align}
where (via WolframAlpha)
$$f(y) = \frac{1}{2} \pi^y \frac{1}{\Gamma(y) \sin(\pi y/2)} + \pi \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-\pi^2/4)^n}{n!} \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(3/2+n)} \frac{1}{y-2-2n}.$$
Here is a Desmos Plot of the function. Note that asymptotically, it seems that $f(y) \sim -\frac{\pi}{y^2}$ and that the poles at $n=1,2,3,\dots$ in the two parts are all exactly canceled.
Thus, the integral is finite because we have (generous bound) $0 < -f(y) < \frac{42}{y^2} \tanh(y)^2$, which is perfectly integrable on $y\in (0,\infty)$.
Unfortunately, I do not have the slightest idea how to approach the integral itself. Splitting it into two parts is out of the question, as they do not converge individually. It is quite remarkable that $f(y)$ itself is such a simple looking (monotonic, no poles, smooth) function, given its origin...

Just a draft based on complex analysis. I'll say in adavance that it doesn't look much promissing to have a closed form.
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\pi z}}{\log(z)}$$
Let's integrate $f(z)$ over the first quadrant of the Complex Plane with small detours around $0$ and $1$.
$$\begin{align}\\
&\oint f( z) dz=\left(\int _{\gamma _{0}} +\int _{0^{+}}^{1^{-}} +\int _{\gamma _{1}} +\int _{1^{+}}^{R} +\int _{\Gamma } +\int _{iR}^{i0^{+}}\right) f( z) dz
\end{align}$$
The only arc that doesn't vanish taking the limits is the one around $z=1$ and it's contribution is $\pi i$.
$$\begin{align}\\
& 0=\pi i-i\int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\pi z}}{\log( z) +\frac{\pi i}{2}} dz+\int _{0}^{\infty } f( z) dz\\
& \Im \int _{0}^{\infty } f( z) dz=\Im \left( -\pi i+i\int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log( z) -\frac{\pi i}{2}}{\log^{2}( z) +\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4}} e^{-\pi z} dz\right) \therefore \\
&\int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin( \pi z)}{\log( z)} dz=-\pi +\underbrace{\int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log( z)}{\log^{2}( z) +\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4}} e^{-\pi z} dz}_{I}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\\
&I=\underbrace{\int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log( z)}{\log^{2}( z) +\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4}} e^{-\pi z} dz}_{z=e^x}=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{x}{x^{2} +\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4}} e^{x-\pi e^{x}} dx
\end{align}$$
Applying Parseval's Theorem
$$\begin{align} &I=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } f( x)\overline{g( x)} dx=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\mathcal{F}( \omega )\overline{\mathcal{G}( \omega )} d\omega =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\underbrace{\left( \pi ^{-( 1-2\pi i\omega )} \Gamma ( 1-2\pi i\omega )\right)\left( i\pi \operatorname{sgn( \omega )} e^{-\pi ^{2} |\omega |}\right) d\omega}_{2\pi\omega\rightarrow x } \\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{0}^{\infty }\left[ \Gamma ( 1-i\omega ) \pi ^{i\omega } -\Gamma ( 1+i\omega ) \pi ^{-i\omega }\right] e^{-\frac{\pi \omega }{2}} d\omega 
\end{align}$$
From this point onward, I'm unsure how to proceed because essentially, one needs to take the Laplace Transform of $\Gamma(1\pm i\omega)$.
